# Asynchronous control flow - returning true after a for loop is completely done

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have the following method in Node.js:

```
var foo = function(items){
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var item = items[i];
        bar(item);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want foo to return true after all of the bar's have finished updating. How do I do that?

EDIT: I am looking for a way to do this without any external libraries if possible.

Comment: foo and bar are synchronous functions, their are no callbacks in their parameters. So there is no need for "Asynchronous control flow"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options to solve what you want, you just need to define the nature of your funcions `foo` and `bar`. Here are some options:

> Your original code doesn't need it:

Your `foo` and `bar` functions doesn't have any `callback` in their parameters so they are not asynchronous.

> Asuming foo function is asynchronous and bar function is synchronous:

You should rewrite your original code using callbacks, something like this:

```
var foo = function(items, fooCallback){
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var item = items[i];
        bar(item);
    }
    fooCallback(true);
}
```

> Using a Async:

You should install it at the beggining:

```
npm install async
```

You use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#each), like this.

```
var async = require('async');

var foo = function(items){
  async.each(items, function(item, callback){
    var _item = item;
    bar(_item);
    callback();
  },
  function(err){
    return true;
  }
  });
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, `async` is a must have in any project. Could control your workflows in many ways, you should read it an learn to use it. It will make your life easier.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of the for loop being "completely done" depends on whether or not `bar` is synchronous or asynchronous. If `bar` is synchronous--perhaps it is doing some long-running computation--then your code already returns when the loop is "completely done".

But based on the part of your question that says

> after all of the bar's have finished updating

it seems to be a reasonable assumption that `bar` is asynchronous--perhaps it is making a network call. But currently it is missing any mechanism to report when it's done. Therefore, the first job is to redefine `bar` so it has an asynchronous interface. There are two basic kinds of asynchronous interfaces. The older, classical node approach is callbacks. A new approach is promises.

In either case, therefore, you need to start off by redefining `bar` in one way or another. You cannot use an interface asynchronously unless it is designed to be used that way.

After we have given `bar` an asynchronous interface, we can then use that from within `foo` to correctly report when the bars are "completely done".

#### Callbacks

In the callback case, we change the calling sequence for `bar` to `bar(item, callback)`, giving it a way to report back when it is done. We will also need a callback on the `foo` routine, to be invoked when all the `bar` calls finish. Following your preference to not use libraries, the logic for this could look something like this:

```
function foo(items, callback) {
  var count = items.length;
  var results = [];

  items.forEach(function(item, idx) {        
    bar(item, function(err, data) {
      if (err) callback(err);
      results[idx] = data;
      if (!count--) callback(null, results);
    });
  });
}
```

This loops over the items, calling `bar` for each one. When each bar finishes, we place its result in a `results` array, and check if this is the final bar, in which case we call the top-level callback.

This would be used as

```
foo(items, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log("Error is", err);
  else console.log("All succeeded, with resulting array of ", data);
});
```

The above is essentially equivalent to using `async.each`, as suggested in another answer, as follows:

```
function foo(items, callback) {
  async.each(items, bar, callback);
}
```

**Waiting for each bar to finish**

If you want to wait for each bar to finish before proceeding to the next one, with `async` it's pretty easy with `eachSeries`:

```
function foo(items, callback) {
  async.eachSeries(items, bar, callback);
}
```

Non-library code would be a bit more complicated:

```
function foo(items, callback) {
  var results = [];

  function next(i) {
    if (i >= items.length) return callback(results));
    bar(items[i], function barCallback(err, data) {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      results[i] = data;
      next(++i);
    });
  }

  next(0);
}
```

Here, the callback reporting that each bar is completed (`barCallback`) calls the `next` routine with incremented `i` to kick off the call to the next bar.

#### Promises

However, you are likely to be better off using promises. In this case, we will design `bar` to return a promise, instead of invoking a callback. Assuming `bar` calls some database routine `MYDB`, the new version of `bar` is likely to look like this:

```
function bar(item) {
  return MYDB.findRecordPromise(item.param);
}
```

If `MYDB` only provides old-fashioned callback-based interfaces, then the basic approach is

```
function bar(item) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    MYDB.findRecord(item.param, function(err, data) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

Now that we have a promise-based version of `bar`, we will define `foo` to return a promise as well, instead of taking an extra callback parameter. Then it's very simple:

```
function foo(items) {
  return Promise.all(items.map(bar));
}
```

`Promise.all` takes an array of promises (which we create from `items` by mapping over `bar`), and fulfills when all of them fulfill, with a value of an array of fulfilled values, and rejects when any of them reject.

This is used as

```
foo(items) . then(
  function(data) { console.log("All succeeded, with resulting array of ", data); },
  function(err)  { console.log("Error is", err); }
);
```

**Waiting for each bar to finish**

If, with the promises approach, you want to wait for each bar to finish before the next one is kicked off, then the basic approach is:

```
function foo(items) {
  return items.reduce(function(promise, item) {
    return promise.then(function() { return bar(item); });
  }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

This starts off with an "empty" (pre-resolved) promise, then each time through the loop, adds a then to the chain to execute the next bar when the preceding one is finished.

If you want to get fancy and use advanced async functions, with the new `await` keyword:

```
async function foo(items) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    await bar(items[i]);
  }
}
```

#### Aside

As an aside, the presumption in another answer that you might be looking for an asynchronous interface to a routine (`foo`) which loops over some calls to `bar` which are either synchronous, or may be asynchronous but can only be kicked off with no way to know when they completed, seems odd. Consider this logic:

```
var foo = function(items, fooCallback){
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var item = items[i];
        bar(item);
    }
    fooCallback(true);
}
```

This does nothing different from the original code, except that instead of returning true, it calls the callback with true. It does not ensure that the bars are actually completed, since, to repeat myself, without giving `bar` a new asynchronous interface, we have no way to know that they are completed.

The code shown using `async.each` suffers from a similar flaw:

```
var async = require('async');

var foo = function(items){
  async.each(items, function(item, callback){
    var _item = item;      // USE OF _item SEEMS UNNECESSARY
    bar(_item);
    callback();            // BAR IS NOT COMPLETED HERE
  },
  function(err){
    return true;           // THIS RETURN VALUE GOES NOWHERE
  });
}
```

This will merely kick off all the bars, but then immediately call the callback before they are finished. The entire `async.each` part will finish more or less instantaneously, immediately after which the final `function(err)` will be invoked; the value of `true` it returns will simply go into outer space. If you wanted to write it this way, it should be

```
var foo = function(items, fooCallback){
  async.each(items, function(item, callback){
    bar(item);
    callback();
  },
  function(err){
    fooCallback(true);           // CHANGE THIS
  }
  });
}
```

but even in this case `fooCallback` will be called pretty much instantaneously, regardless of whether the bars are finished or whether they returned errors.

Comment: This answer is very good as well! I want to ask -- is there any way to make sure the for-loop executes in order? IE. the for loop executes for i=0, then after it finishes it goes to 1=1, etc.